# How to show/hide instead toggle icon?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to show/hide icon instead to right now toggle icon.
Code:

```
                <td *ngIf="isActive !== i" (click)="clickerTrue(set, i)">
                  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/30/000000/plus.png"/>
                </td>
                <td *ngIf="isActive === i">  
                  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="set.note" name="value" class="form-control" /> 
              </td>
```

`i` is index from `ngFor`

```
  clickerTrue(set, index) { 
    this.isActive = this.isActive === index ? null : index; 
  }
```

`isActive` variable first value is false.

Comment: I don't understand the question the way it is written now. Please provide a Stackblitz, or some additional information, such as expected results.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ngFor ... why not pass the object?

```
<button *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="toggleActive(item)">click me</button>


toggleActive(item) {
  item.active = !item.active;
}
```

Comment: What is item.active. When i console.log item.active i got undefined

Comment: My mistake, i thought you were storing the state on the object.  
which would allow you to update the state separately for each object.  Which you could unset other objects in the set if needed.

Answer (score -1):

### it is work in *ngFor

```
<td *ngIf="isActive != set" (click)="clickerTrue(set, i)">
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/office/30/000000/plus.png"/>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="isActive == set">  
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="set.note" name="value" class="form-control" /> 
          </td>
```

---

```
public isActive: any;

clickerTrue (set: any, index: number) { 
    this.isActive = set; 
}
```

Comment: Please check it is help to you.

Comment: check this new soluction It is work for me in my demo project.